# Start Unity from C++ (decoupling control and visualization)

Tags: c#, c++, linux, opengl, unity-game-engine

I'm running Unity on Linux and in C++ I have a set of controllers (and physics) for transforming objects. Currently, I am using Qt and OpenGL to display it. I was wondering, how would I exchange my Qt, OpenGL implementation with a more serious thing as Unity? - In short, could I feed unity from C++ with information about my objects status, which Unity would then visualize?

Comment: I think a better design would be to make it the other way around, and to let Unity handle the main event loop and handling and only calling out to time-critical parts implemented in C++ when (and if!) needed.

Comment: I think the only option to use C++ in Unity are [NativePlugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html). But why do you consider Qt and OpenGL to be unserious? My experience with Qt was great, and there are many applications (open source and commercial) that are built with Qt.

Comment: removed the last sentence, because it made the otherwise ok-ish question into offtopic

Comment: @Skynet I don't consider OpenGl and Qt unserios. Maybe my choice of words was poor, but what I would like is to be more compatible with the mainstream? - let's say...
Someprogrammerdude I know that the other way around is more natural for Unity, but this is just the way I need to do it. Maybe, an -so library with an interface, implemented in unity.. ? and then another -so library to return the control to my C++ code? The thing is, I need to have the control from C++, I don't really care how the control gets to Unity. (but it should be native, so no sockets)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Unity was specifically designed for the purposes you stated above, and it'll probably be painstakingly difficult to modify it.

To be honest, the better you create the animations and models, the better (for any game design engine) your graphics will be. Not sure if that is the problem this is pertaining to, but the built in graphics programs are merely tools. It takes the design to make a stunning game.